# How to skip a For Loop iteration if the cell is blank?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, skip

For Loop j pulls from the cells (A:A). If that cell is blank I want to skip *that* loop.

I tried an `if then` statement in j. If the cell is empty ("") skip *that* loop and go to the next j loop.

```vb
For j = 0 To 20 'Number of Tail # Cells

    If Cells(j, 3) = "" Then
        j = j + 1
        
    Else
        NewestEntry = Worksheets(Tail(j)).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
            
    End If
```

Comment: What kind of loop are you doing?

Comment: I'm new to VBA. Im still learning, but a for loop? I forgot that in the code. ```For j = 0 to 20```

Comment: Then just remove the `j=j+1` and it will work

Comment: When using a `For` loop you should not be adjusting the loop counter within the loop: if you *need* to do that then it's a sign you need a different type of loop.

Comment: Research the vba function is `IsEmpty`. So `If IsEmpty(Cells(j,3)) then`

Comment: @pgSystemTester maybe, maybe not.  Depends on the nature of the data on the sheet.  Eg Formula that might return empty strings

Comment: @pgSystemTester Since this post I've been trying to use `If IsEmpty(Cells(j,3)) then` and its not working. Thats the line its getting hung up on. It gives me a `1004` runtime error: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, right that's why I proposed it. Perhaps there was an issue of an `empty` cell and a cell that has `=""`. I figured maybe that might be the issue. Looks like it isn't.

Comment: @pgSystemTester. FWIW `=""` tests true for both empty strings and empty cells.  `IsEmpty` only tests true for empty cells

Answer (score 0):

Don't increment the loop counter. Just condition the logic on not blank.

```
For j = ...
   If Cells(j, 3).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

Note that cell references start from 1, not 0

Comment: That did not work. It gave me a `1004` runtime error:  runtime error: Application-defined or object-defined error. I've also tried using `IsEmpty = False` and doing it backwards. It did not fix anything.

Comment: Nothing in what I posted would cause a variable not set error.  If you want help debugging your code, I'd suggest you post another question asking for that.  Just be sure to include everything we will need to help: a [MRE], the line of code that causes the error, the error itself, the values of relevant variables when the error occurs, some sample data (as text), and your expected results

Comment: ok! I will try doing that! Thanks for your help!